# Excessive denied requests for port 58322 in syslog

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

My iptables is setup to block all unneeded ports as it should but I'm checking my syslog due to these random but all-to-frequent apache2 crashes and I noticed a lot of requests such as this. In all the archived syslogs that I have these are present from different IP addresses.

There is a similar question with an accepted here: [What service uses UDP port 60059?](https://serverfault.com/questions/295485/what-service-uses-udp-port-60059)

```
Jun  4 06:49:27 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=218.7.74.50 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=115 ID=27636 PROTO=UDP SPT=9520 DPT=58322 LEN=109
Jun  4 06:49:31 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=95.160.226.177 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=31468 PROTO=UDP SPT=47642 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:49:54 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=78.137.36.10 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=21872 PROTO=UDP SPT=57872 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:50:14 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=111.253.217.11 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=28882 PROTO=UDP SPT=51826 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:51:02 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=189.45.114.173 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x16 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=19985 PROTO=UDP SPT=41087 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:51:09 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=87.89.202.28 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=7874 PROTO=UDP SPT=17524 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:51:20 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=24.44.124.35 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=12978 PROTO=UDP SPT=45596 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:51:22 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=81.174.48.236 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=93 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=21352 DPT=58322 LEN=73
Jun  4 06:51:23 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=124.107.61.84 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=13038 PROTO=UDP SPT=14357 DPT=58322 LEN=111
Jun  4 06:51:30 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=88.8.23.200 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=123 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=21062 PROTO=UDP SPT=4291 DPT=58322 LEN=103
Jun  4 06:51:54 HOSTNAME kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fe:fd:ad:ff:dd:95:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=80.202.244.234 DST=MY.SERVER.IP.HERE LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=339 PROTO=UDP SPT=14020 DPT=58322 LEN=109
```

I'm not overly experienced with server configuration and debugging, so I only just installed logcheck after reading that previous question.

I guess my question is what steps should I take after reading this log info to 1) further protect myself, 2) understand if this could be causing any other problems with my VPS, and 3) use this data to help others?

Comment: Or should I be unconcerned with this entirely since iptables is doing it's job? Was just curious why it's that port specifically that gets all the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iptables is doing it's job - confirm nothing unexpected is listening by checking `netstat` (just like in your referenced question) - and the answer on that other question applies as well.

I see this all the time on clients that don't have a perimeter firewall in place.